# Two dimensional arrays error

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
double NUMB_COLS = 3;

void readMatrix(int matr[] [3], int numb_rows, int numb_cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<numb_rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numb_cols; j++)
        {
            cout <<"[" << i << "] [" <<j <<"] =";
            cin >> matr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void printMatr(int matr[][3], int numb_rows, int numb_cols)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numb_rows; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < numb_cols; j++)
       {
           cout << "[" << i << "][" << j << "] = " <<  matr[i][j];
       } 
           cout << endl;
  }
}
int main()
{
    int matr[5][10];
    printMatr(matr, 4, 5);
    readMatrix(matr, 4, 5);
return 0;
}
```

The error is

> 31 23  C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\programs\arrays2.cpp   [Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int (*)[3]' for argument '1' to 'void readMatrix(int (*)[3], int, int)'

What to do??

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the correct subscripts.

```
void readMatrix(int matr[5][10], int numb_rows, int numb_cols)
```

a std::vector would be a lot easier in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is, that you pass a pointer to `matr` to a function expecting a different array layout. Remember that all `int`s in `matr` are consecutive in memory. Even if you did cast your `matr` to the expected type before passing it to the function, what was at position `matr[0][7]` in `main()` will end up in position `matr[2][1]` inside `readMatrix()`.

The second error is, that your function accepts a column count, even though it already declared the column count to be `3`. Such inconsistencies are an ample source of bugs, and should be avoided at all cost. Unfortunately, C++ forbids you to use dynamically sized array types, so you cannot just change your function declaration to

```
void readMatrix(int numb_rows, int numb_cols, int matr[numb_rows][numb_cols]) {
```

as you can in C.

The easiest way to fix your problem is probably to use `std::vector<>`.

Comment: You can do: `<template unsigned R, unsigned C> void readMatrix(int matr[R][C]`

Comment: Yes, you can. But I, for one, do not think that would be good idea. It only passes on the problem of the fixed array bounds to the calling code. If you go down this road, you quickly arrive at a situation where virtually all of your code is templated, very inflexible, producing tons of error messages when you get it wrong, and ghastly to read. I have written such code myself, and I regret it. Now I think twice before I scream "template"...

Answer (score 1):

You defined the array in main as

```
int matr[5][10];
```

but in the functions the corresponding parameter is defined as

```
int matr[][3]
```

They are different types.

If you want to use in the functions only a part of the array int matr[5][10]; that is only 4 first rows and 5 first columns then you have to define the corresponding parameter of the functions the same way as the original array that is as

```
int matr[][10];
```

For example

```
void printMatr(int matr[][10], int numb_rows, int numb_cols)
```

Or you have to change code in main and write

```
int matr[5][3];
printMatr(matr, 5, 3);
readMatrix(matr, 5, 3);
```

Also take into account that you defined variable

```
double NUMB_COLS = 3;
```

but do not use it (thogh it should be defined having integral type).

If you would write

```
const int NUMB_COLS = 3;
```

and then use it in array definitions there would not be such an error. For example

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int NUMB_COLS = 3;

void readMatrix(int matr[] [NUMB_COLS], int numb_rows, int numb_cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<numb_rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numb_cols; j++)
        {
            cout <<"[" << i << "] [" <<j <<"] =";
            cin >> matr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void printMatr(int matr[][NUMB_COLS], int numb_rows, int numb_cols)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numb_rows; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < numb_cols; j++)
       {
           cout << "[" << i << "][" << j << "] = " <<  matr[i][j];
       } 
           cout << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
    int matr[5][NUMB_COLS];

    printMatr(matr, 5, NUMB_COLS);
    readMatrix(matr, 5, NUMB_COLS);

    return 0;
}
```

You can assign   NUMB_COLS any number including 10 used in your original code. The code I showed will not depend on "magic numbers". It uses only named constant NUMB_COLS